# Complex JSON in Swift. How to get the data correctly. Different structures

Tags: json, swift, struct

Faced a difficult problem for me, when receiving data I don’t know how to decompose data in one array.

The responsible variable contains different types of data.

Do I get it right? I think in the initializer to go through the possible options and substitute the desired one? What type should the variable of this array be?

```
[
  {
    "id": 42,
    "created_at": "2021-09-08T08:55:58.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-09-08T08:55:58.000000Z",
    "link": "u4986",
    "type": "u",
    "responsible": {
      "id": 4986,
      "type": "management_company",
      "email": "X@X.com",
      "phone": "+0000000000",
      "comment": null,
      "first_name": "Alex",
      "second_name": "Hook"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 43,
    "created_at": "2021-09-08T08:55:58.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-09-08T08:55:58.000000Z",
    "link": "r14",
    "type": "r",
    "responsible": {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "manager",
      "guard_name": "api",
      "created_at": "2021-06-15T19:20:20.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-06-15T19:20:20.000000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

How to make an initializer for MyJson

```
struct MyJson: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let createdAt: String
    let updatedAt: String
    let link: String
    let type: String
    let responsible: Any
}

// MARK: - Responsible
struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let type, email, phone, comment: String
    let firstName, secondName: String
}

struct UserCategory: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, guardName, createdAt, updatedAt: String
}
```

Comment: https://app.quicktype.io ? There is nothing complexe about your JSON. Make Codable structures.

Comment: `Any` is not supported in `Codable`. The best solution for the different `responsible` types is an enum with associated values. If the different types are uniquely related to the `type` value it's pretty easy

Comment: User?  Where does it come from?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Completed the task for a very long time. Finally I solved the problem. If you are facing this problem. You will find the solution here [Indeterminate Types with Codable in Swift](https://medium.com/makingtuenti/indeterminate-types-with-codable-in-swift-5a1af0aa9f3d)

Comment: It would be better if you could put some words on how you solved the problem in your self-answer so that future readers won't have to rely on your link working for them to figure out what you did.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

In swift JSON parsing is pretty straightforward, build an object that reflects your JSON (I've just built an example based on your JSON here):

```
struct JsonExample: Decodable {
  let id: Int
  let responsible: [Responsible]

  struct Responsible: Decodable {
      let id: Int
      let email: String
      let guard_name: String
  }
}
```

and then just decode it

```
let jsonData = "json_string".data(using: .utf8)!
do {
      let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([JsonExample].self, from: jsonData)
            
} catch let error {
      print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

If you want to distinguish between nested objects you can use init and use a property inside your JSON to get the job done

```
init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.id = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    let type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
    if type == "a" {
         let data = try container.decode([ResponsibleA].self, forKey: . responsible)
         responsible = .responsibleA(data)
    } else { // add better error handling
         let data = try container.decode([ResponsibleB].self, forKey: . responsible)
         responsible = .responsibleB(data)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please note that Responsible has a different type

Comment: just fill Responibile with all properties that your JSON can return, you don't need to init them all

Comment: An array can contain different structures. not only these. If I do it all in one, it will be a very large structure. I use the User structure in another part of the program, I do not need fields that do not belong to it